# Put Python/Tkinter into an application icon

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a program in Python, then created a GUI using Tkinter. When I use programs on my computer (like Microsoft Word), I don't need to access the GUI from the command line I just click the application icon.

How do I put my program (the program itself is in the same .py file as the GUI) into an application icon that will start my program?

Comment: By "starting it" do you mean to edit it when you open it?

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND It's an application that collects values from the user and writes them out to file (very simple). I have to open the GUI from the command line (something like python /simple.py).

When you use a program you buy (say Spotify, or Word, or Outlook, etc.), instead of starting it from the command line, you just click an icon, and it opens the program. I would like my program to open by clicking on icon rather than starting it from the command line. Does that make sense?

Comment: You understand python, but not shortcuts? I call shenanigans!

Comment: @Hiroto No shenaniganS! I'm self taught, so occasionally I'm missing basic things

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to in Windows is a *shortcut link*.
The equivalent in *nix environments would be the `ln -s` command.

Links in computer systems are special files that point to a different file, often with parameters for easy access. See the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut) on them for more information. Windows shortcuts are files with the extension `.lnk`, whereas soft links in Linux have the mode `+l`.

If I wanted to link to a file on Windows using Python, I would right click and create a shortcut. If your python installation is old (below 2.7.3), there is a little bug in the installation where the regkeys `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py` are misconfigured and don't pass on command line arguments, so a fail-safe when passing arguments would be to edit the shortcut link and stick in something like the following:

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\dev\path\to\file.py --args"
```

Windows can execute a program from a shortcut link or link files and directories directly (called *symbolic links*), whereas linux would link files or directories and then call that interpreter with a shebang (`#!`) or a direct command (`./`) in order to execute it. Windows just pretty much links the program to execute with the arguments after it.

You can also just double-click the file in explorer, but this doesn't supply arguments (if you need them).

Comment: Note, that Windows *does* support symbolic links to files and directories, as well as directory junctions.

Comment: Oh cool. Is this significantly different to implement on a mac?

Comment: @PhilBraun nope, but I'd do what you normally do on linux and make a shell script to start the `.app` correctly and then just start it from that